# You hate h̶a̶t̶s̶ reputation? Click here to get rid of it

Tags: javascript, stackexchange, ecmascript-6, userscript

Soo... I recently read a meta-post about the inherent problems of reputation. It listed some things like:

- Confirmation bias.
- Demotivating for low-rep users.
- Hubris and elitism of high-rep users over low-rep users.
- Incorrect representation of competence.
- ...

So I thought to myself: "How would the network be, just without reputation?"

I grabbed the inspector, checked questions, my profile page and the active page and how reputation is displayed.

Then I quickly hacked together the following small user-script (ECMA6) for Greasemonkey that would hide all reputation from sight:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Reputation Hider
// @namespace    http://gihub.com/Vogel612/ReputationHider
// @version      0.1
// @description  Hides all reputation displays from StackExchange sites
// @author       Vogel612
// @grant        none
// @include      /https?:\/\/(meta\.)?.*\.stackexchange\.com\/.*/
// @include      /https?:\/\/(stackoverflow|serverfault|superuser|askubuntu)\.com\/.*/
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';

let slice = function(collection) {
  return [].slice.call(collection);   
}

let repClasses = [ "rep", "reputation", "reputation-score" ];

let hideRepz = function() {
  repClasses.forEach(clazz => 
    slice(document.getElementsByClassName(clazz))
      .forEach(el => { 
        // this results in minor inconsistencies in CSS, but alas
        el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      })
    );
}

hideRepz();
// add event listener for live-updates
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", hideRepz);
```

This has been running for a while now for me and I like to say it's a refreshing change. That aside:

It hides all reputation numbers on the page. If you're curious you can still find them of course. Also it looks funny on `/questions` when the active timers are outdented differently, but that's just my OCD going mad there.
It also checks for new questions you load over the notification.

What can I do better in that userscript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, the network where everything's made up and the points don't matter.

Comment: Why are you using JS for this? Wouldn't custom CSS solve this better (and much easier)?

Comment: @Bergi while I did get Greasemonkey I don't customize enough to go for Stylish.... so no CSS. That would arguably be easier though, yes

Comment: You could do the same from a userscript actually. Just `document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style")).textContent = ".rep, .reputation, .reputation-scope { visibility: hidden; }";`

Comment: Will you post this on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts)?

Comment: @A.L. I didn't intend to originally, but now I am considering. I would add some more functionality though before doing that. Feel free to post yourself, even though it's 3 lines of CSS for that matter

Comment: As an extension to @IlmariKaronen's aswer, consider hiding just the class `.-flair`. This alone will disable the view of reputation and badges, which I find are strongly correlated.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It would be better to do this with a [user style](http://webdesign.about.com/od/userstylesheets/a/aa010906.htm), e.g. using the [Stylus](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus) extension, like this:

```css
.rep, .reputation, .reputation-score {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

One advantage of user styles over scripts is that they're applied as soon as the page starts to load, so you won't see the rep counts flicker briefly while the page is loading.  Also, user styles will automatically apply also to new dynamic content loaded e.g. via Ajax (such as new answers posted while you're viewing the page).

If you insist on using a user *script*, it's possibly to emulate user styles by using [`@run-at document-start`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at) and injecting a custom `style` element into the page early, like this:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Hide Stack Exchange reputation (demo)
// @namespace   http://vyznev.net/
// @description A demonstration of using style injection to emulate user styles
// @author      Ilmari Karonen
// @version     1.0
// @license     Public domain
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @homepageURL http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/120100
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var css =
    ".rep, .reputation, .reputation-score {\n" +
    "    visibility: hidden;\n" +
    "}\n";

var style = document.createElement('style');
style.textContent = css;
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(style);
```

I use this method in my [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script (which combines a bunch of more or less minor interface bugfixes and improvements together) to let me efficiently apply both CSS-only and JS-based tweaks from a single user script.

One detail worth noting is that styles injected this way will generally end up being included *before* any actual site style sheets on the page, which means that they will be overridden by site CSS selectors of equal specificity.  In some cases, you may need to use `!important` and/or various [specificity hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062256/select-elements-with-randomly-generated-ids-with-css/35065825#35065825) to make sure that your custom styles will take precedence.

Comment: If ES6 is available, best use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) instead of concatenating.

Answer (score 29):

You could use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassName`. That way, you have a bit more flexibility in targeting elements. It also allows multiple selectors. That way, you don't have to loop twice.

Instead of `[].slice` which uses an unnecessary array as host, try using `Array.prototype.slice.call` instead. Longer, but without that extra array.

Also, try using `display:none` as visibility just hides the element but maintain layout. This way, there's no awkward whitespace where the reputation was, making the layout all natural.

Seeing that you put ES6, we can use the handy dandy arrow functions as well.

```
'use strict';

const REPUTATION_ELEMENTS = '.rep, .reputation, .reputation-score';

function getElementArray(selector){
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}

document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", event => {
  getElementArray(REPUTATION_ELEMENTS).forEach( element => {
    element.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

Comment: The `display:none`advice is worth gold. One small thing: this doesn't run when loading the page by default. That's just a really minor thing. Also I recall hearing something about `querySelectorAll` being slower than the more specialized calls, but I might be wrong. Thanks for the review :)

Comment: If you're using ES6, you should rather use a `for of` loop instead of `forEach`.

Comment: Another way to hide things: `element.hidden = true`. [ciu](http://caniuse.com/#search=hidden), [whatwg](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-hidden-attribute)

Comment: @Vogel612 Yup, it's relatively slower than the older element selection APIs, but for a few elements it's probably negligible and more familiar because of jQuery. Speaking of jQuery, not sure if possible, but if the userscript can utilize the one that is already on the page, it can be as simple as `$(selector).hide()`.

Comment: @Bergi `forEach` just came out of instinct, especially with arrays. :D

Answer (score 16):

## Update url

UserScripts have the magical ability to update themselves if you provide a link to a raw version of your script as a UserScript header:

Note: You actually have to increase the version, or it won't update.

> ```
> // ==UserScript==
> // @name         Reputation Hider
> // @namespace    http://gihub.com/Vogel612/ReputationHider
> // @version      0.1
> // @downloadURL
> // @updateURL
> ```

---

## Method

I'm not particularly a fan of your method.

Checking for DOM updates before scanning through everything all over again.

It would make more sense to simply inject a stylesheet to override SE's stylesheets.

Much more labour performant.

---

## ES6 features

I like the use of ES6 in your code, but you haven't used it to its full potential:

> ```
> let slice = function(collection) {
>   return [].slice.call(collection);   
> }
> ```

Instead of using the old `function(collection){}` way, you can use `(collection) => ()`:

```
let slice = (collection) => [].slice.call(collection)
```

The same thing applies to the function in your main loop.

---

## Slicing and Dicing

Currently, you only use `slice` with your element selection.
You should combine the two!

> ```
> slice(document.getElementsByClassName(clazz))
> ```

```
let fetchElements(clazz) => [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName(clazz))
```

Or hey, let's take it a step further and do some concatenation magic:

```
let fetchElements = (clazzArrey) =>
    clazzArrey.map((clazz) => [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName(clazz)))
```

Alternatively, you can use string concatenation to make one huge selector string and use `querySelectorAll` as Joseph described.

I find that `querySelector*` can have worse performance, but its always been edge cases that trigger that for me.

---

### Future gazing

This isn't usually a review point I add, however, I think you could add support for other fields, and make a handy dandy dialog box to choose which you want to hide. That'd be a StackApps worthy creation in my eyes.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `document.getElementsByClassName`, you can use `document.querySelectorAll(CSS selector)`.

Edit(Reply to @200_success):
You can use anyone of those. Just I prefer `document.querySelectorAll` since I think it is better **a little**.

1. `document.getElementsByClassName` has 31 letters, and `document.querySelectorAll` has 25 letters.
2. `document.querySelectorAll` uses CSS to get DOM elements, but `document.getElementsByClassName` does not.
3. IE **8+** supports `document.querySelectorAll`(IE 8 only supports CSS2 selectors), but `document.getElementsByClassName` is for IE **9+**.

And **you don't have to make an `Array`** from the `DOMNodeList` using `slice`, since a `DOMNodeList` object is `Array`-like. i.e.  you can use it **as** an `Array` using `Array.prototype.forEach.call(DOMNodeList, callbackFunction)`.

```
window.addEventListener("load", _ => {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".rep, .reputation, .reputation-score, .-flair"), element => {
            element.style.display = "none";
        });
});
```

Comment: Or, `for(const element of arraylike);`.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using ES6, you could replace your `slice` function with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) like this (implementing Josephs changes too);

```
let hideRepz = function() {
  repClasses.forEach(clazz => 
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`.${clazz}`))
      .forEach(el => { 
        el.style.display = 'none';
      })
    );
}
```

Comment: If you're using ES6, you should rather use a `for of` loop instead of `forEach`.

Comment: @Bergi Other than the "it's there, so let's use it" argument, is there a concrete reason why `for(..of..)` is preferable?

Comment: It's somewhere between "more concise, more elegant, more performant, less to type, easier to understand" - if there was an adjective like "pythonic" for JS, it would be that. The technical arguments are that it doesn't require intermediate arrays and that you can `break` from it; basically `forEach` is deprecated with ES6.

Answer (score 5):

## Avoid using deprecated events

Mutation Events (`DOMNodeInserted`) [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) and you should [use Mutation Observers instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Sample usage:

```
function processNewNodes(topNode) {
    var nodes = topNode.querySelectorAll(selector);
    // ...
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, processNewNodes);
    });
});

observer.observe(document, {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true
});
```